# Erro de modulo ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, typescript

Quando eu crio uma pagina o modulo não está sendo reconhecido, por exemplo user page e signup no meu caso não estão sendo reconhecidos, como solucionar?
segue a imagem em anexo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como estão os códigos? Como está o arquivo `userpage.ts`? No `import` o nome da sua classe está correta? Você definiu como `Userpage` quando deveria ser `UserPage`.

Comment: Acho que o problema está no `import`. Você está chamando `..pages/` e pelos diretórios mostrados na imagem e no próprio `import` do `HomePage` deveria ser `../pages/` e não `..pages/`.

Answer (score 0):

voce precisa criar páginas através do comando dentro da pasta do seu projeto.

abra o cmd, aponte para a pasta e digite o comando `ionic generate page [nome]`